# How to find a reduced residue system modulo of a number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The reduced residue system modulo $10$ is: $1, 3, 7, 9$
But how could we find these numbers?
The only thing I know is they're relatively prime to $10$. 
What does it mean by "no two different elements of the set are congruent to modulo m"?

Thanks,
Chan

Comment: If you know that they are relatively prime to 10, isn't that your answer?

Comment: @PEV: Thanks, I understand it now. How about the second part "no two different elements of the set are congruent to modulo m". Could you help me explain this as well?

Comment: Exactly. the first part gives the solution while the second part tell when to stop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line "no two different elements of the set are congruent modulo $m$" just means that all of your elements are distinct modulo $m$.  For example, $1,3,7,9,11,111,1111$ are all relatively prime to $10$, but they do **not**  form a reduced residue system since $1,11,111,1111$ are all the same modulo $10$

Another way to specify the condition is:  The reduced residue system modulo $N$ is the set of all integers $m$ with $\gcd(m,N)=1$ and $0\leq m\leq N$.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you refer to the Wikipedia definition of [reduced residue system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_residue_system). The point of the definition is to specify a system of representatives for the $\rm\:phi(n)\:$ congruence classes that are units (invertible) $\rm\ (mod\ n)\:.\:$ This amounts to choosing a set  of $\rm\:\phi(n)\:$ integers coprime to $\rm\:n\:$ such they they are all distinct $\rm\ (mod\ m)\:$.

Comment: How on earth do you think this answer is better.  This is unclear at best unless you already understand the material.